# Background Substruction between images using transparent background

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to get the difference between two images using the following code:

```
Mat getWithoutBackground(Mat img, Mat back)
{
    _backgroundSubVal = 50;
    cv::Mat diff;
    cv::absdiff(img, back, diff);

    cv::Mat diff1Channel;
    cv::cvtColor(diff, diff1Channel, CV_BGRA2GRAY);

    cv::Mat mask = diff1Channel > _backgroundSubVal;

    cv::Mat data(img.size(), CV_8UC4, Scalar(255,255,255,0));

    // copy masked area
    img.copyTo(data, mask);
    cv::imwrite(""1.png", data);
    return similarRegions;
}
```

first is the background:
[image]

second is the actual image:
[image]

and here is the result:
[image]

and I am almost getting the correct solution but i would have liked to have a transparent background instead of black.
(I dont want to remove all of the picture's black colors)
I thought that the 4'th parameter in the Scalar should have done the trick for having a transparent background but i guess that I am missing something..

> ```
>     cv::Mat data(img.size(), CV_8UC4, Scalar(255,255,255,0));
> ```

any ideas what am i doing wrong?

Comment: for each pixel position: if the mask value is 0: set the 4th channel value to zero. Set it to 255 otherwise. So basically, your mask will become the 4th channel.

Comment: afterwards: save as .png . opencv doesnt handle slpha channel during rendering.